# Azure Appfabric Service bus configuration error

Tags: windows, azure

I am using azure app fabric service bus example but when Im trying to run the example i am getting sercurity exception "assembly does not allow partially trusted callers".
Please guide me how to configure the sample example

Regards,
ajay beniwal

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because you have to run Visual Studio as administrator when working with the Dev Fabric. On the Start menu right click on VS2010 and select "Run as Administrator".